# how do I find the current date in buildbot in the main.cfg

Tags: buildbot

In buildbot in the main.cfg file, I need to get the current date and create a folder with the name of the current date. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You give little context as to why and how often you wish to do this, so I will just take the question at face value and assume you want to create the directory when the master.cfg file is first read, i.e. when Buildbot is started.

Put this somewhere in the config file:

```
import datetime
import os 

current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
dirname = current_date.isoformat()
os.makedirs(dirname)
```

#### EDIT 2013-08-30

In order to do a build in a new directory every time it runs, you will have to do something along the following (warning, I haven't tested this myself):

```
import datetime
def date_workdir(*args):
    return datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()

build = factory.BuildFactory()
build.workdir = date_workdir

build.addStep(...)
...
builders.append({
     'name': 'datebuilder',
     'slavename': 'myslave',
     'builddir': 'datebuilder',
     'factory': build})
```

For more info, I suggest you read up on `BuildStep`, `BuildFactory` and their `workdir` attribute.

Comment: I want to have a new directory every time the build runs and put the date of the build in the current directory

Comment: @user1796624 here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793722/how-to-a-create-a-daily-build-folder-using-buildbot

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that understand you correctly, but you may add step like that (for Linux):

```
_command = 'mkdir `date +"%y-%m-%d-`folder_name'
ShellCommand(command=_command, workdir=_workdir, ...)
```